# Socket.io hang up when connection bandwith is low - program does not finish

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I got 2 internet prowider, when I run my node.js scraper on hight bandwith - everything is ok. But when I run scraper on low bandwith socket.io does not receive some of the data, program does not finish. It just stop somewhere in the middle where moust of the data is send. For exmaple if I-m downloading images, if ithere is many images on the page, program just stuck... however there is no error...

Any idea how to resolve this problem?

Comment: It's unlikely we can help you with both seeing your code and without more diagnostic information.

Comment: What info do you need? I'm using many socket emits from server to user some only with few bytes (~15 emits) some with approximately 20KB (~10 emits). Everything is send in about 30 seconds (in that time, program run from start to end).

Comment: We'd have to see your code to now where to start.  It could be anything.  For example, with slow connections, you could end up with too many connections open at once, using too many resources on your server.  Questions about code here MUST include relevant code.  We can't guess what your code looks like and what the problems are with it.  Include relevant code.

Comment: The code is loooong and big but I try to put part on github. Server is  above suspicion (local machine). This is tested with ONE client that receive data on low bandwitch - and he can't receive it.

Comment: But, are you scraping lots of web sites?  Can't really help without seeing the code.